# PHP trying to allocate 127 TB of memory and memory leak with preg_match and preg_replace

Tags: php, apache, unicode, memory-leaks, preg-match

I think I have found a problem that seems to create a memory leak in Apache / PHP when unicode characters as a delimiter or sometimes anywhere in a regular expression with `preg_match` and `preg_replace`. It is possible that this happens in more `preg_*` methods.

### Test case 1

Create a new PHP file `test.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php
    preg_match( '°test°i', 'test', $matches );
```

### Test case 2

Create a new PHP file `test.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php
    preg_match( '°', 'test', $matches );
```

<sup>The unicode character `°` used as a delimiter is the degree sign. Try any other unicode character to see what happens, if you like.</sup>

### Result

Having uploaded the file to a webserver with `Apache 2.4.10 (Debian)` and `PHP 5.6.0-1+b1`, run it from your favourite browser. Expect to see a blank page or a message saying either "invalid response" or "this page could not be loaded".

This will result in the following two lines in your Apache error.log (usually /var/log/error.log):

```
[Mon Dec 15 10:31:09.941622 2014] [:error] [pid 6292] [client ###.###.###.###:64413] PHP Warning:  preg_match():  in /path/to/test.php on line 2
[Mon Dec 15 10:31:09.941796 2014] [:error] [pid 6292] [client ###.###.###.###:64413] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 139979759686648 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Note that the amount of bytes PHP tried to allocate is just over 127 Terabytes.

### You need to restart Apache now

Running PHP scripts after trying out the above script will result in all kinds of notices or fatal errors that pop-up even in code that shouldn't even be able to produce them. For instance, autoloading extended classes does not seem to work correctly anymore and may display errors like the following:

`Class MyClass not found in file MyExtendingClass.php on Line 3`

And the file MyExtendingClass.php would look like this:

```
<?php
    class MyExtendingClass extends MyClass
    {
    }
```

As you can see `MyClass` is clearly on line 2 and even though it does exist and the autoloader has been set up correctly, PHP can't find it anymore.

Obviously, don't use unicode characters in regular expressions. But why does PHP leak memory when using certain unicode characters? Is there an explanation for this behavior? I'd like to know why PHP thinks it should allocate such a vast amount of bytes.

#### System information

Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.0-1+b1 OpenSSL/1.0.1i configured

Comment: Try to upgrade your PHP.

Comment: Or downgrade, but better still, report your bug at: https://bugs.php.net

Comment: Tested on OSX 10.10 with PHP/5.5.19 CLI and PHP/5.5.14 on Apache/2.4.9. Both reported `PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash` and no memory limit or leak reached. Maybe it's a bug introduced on PHP 5.6.

Comment: `<b>Warning</b>:  preg_match():  in <b>C:\random\test.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />` for me when I tried to `print_r(preg_match ('°lol°i','trolololo'));`

Comment: PHP/5.6.3 CLI (OSX 10.10, Homebrew) reports `PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash` and does not crash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar error, with PHP trying to load into RAM something slighlty bigger than 127 TB, but to me it happens AFTER the script is finished.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 140683487706824 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm using PHP version 5.4.39-0+deb7u2, and I see it happen after the script execution because the script itself works just fine and shows no issues. I actually tried logging the script execution time and RAM usage and it was all just fine, until the end of the script.

My issue is most likely related to using the dblib+freetds combination, for connecting to remote MSSQL server, from Debian, which is a [known bug #64511](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64511). It's actually reported fixed, but in my case it doesn't seem so.

It's actually very hard to get any rules in this behavior, but here's what I see.

- I connect to the remote MSSQL
- perform a query (which actually consists of a call to a stored procedure and then executes a SELECT query right after it)

After execution, if I would use something like this code to fetch the results:

```
$sprocResultSet = $PDOquery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$PDOquery->nextRowset();
$sprocExitCode = $PDOquery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

in **most** of the cases, I'd get that weird RAM allocation error, with supposedly terabytes being loaded.

When instead of specifying the fetch style inside the fetchAll(), I used a setFetchMode(), like here:

```
$PDOquery->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sprocResultSet = $PDOquery->fetchAll();
$PDOquery->nextRowset();
$sprocExitCode = $PDOquery->fetchAll();
```

then I never noticed the same error with allocating RAM.

I did try closing the cursors and nulling the $PDOquery variable, or just letting it auto-close on script end - none helped. Also, maybe important to mention - both the sproc and the additional SELECT query after it are getting back just one line of data, so there's definitely no big result set coming back.

So... I'm not sure if this helps in all cases, but if you have similar situation as myself, try setting that default fetch mode for PDO in advance.

> And just two things to add. First, in the code above, the PDO's nextResultSet() is used, which is also reported as a bug - causing an issue with memory: [nextRowset causes memory corruption](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67130).
>   Second, PDO's fetch() is NOT used, because whenever used it would die with DBLIB error reported.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Although this doesn't officially count as an answer, it might help other developers figure out the source of similar problems.

Comment: Welcome. And that was exactly my thinking when I wrote it. ;)